# Open_basedir restricting HTTPS requests only?

Tags: plesk, vhosts, open-basedir

I've tried everything and I can't remove open_basedir for HTTPS requests. It's working for HTTP requests though. Plesk 10 is my control panel.

Here are the steps I've taken:

I created a vhost.conf file that has the restriction removed.
I created a vhost_ssl.conf file that has the restriction removed.
I reconfigured Plesk.
I restarted apache.

Does anyone know know what the problem is?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in the vhost_ssl.conf file. This line:

```
<Directory /var/www/vhosts/XXX.com/subdomains/app/httpsdocs>
```

Should have been...

```
<Directory /var/www/vhosts/XXX.com/subdomains/app/httpdocs>
```

I erroneously thought the folder for the secure content was being loaded from httpsdocs.

My complete vhost_ssl.conf file now looks like this:

```
<Directory /var/www/vhosts/XXX.com/subdomains/app/httpdocs>

<IfModule sapi_apache2.c>
  php_admin_flag engine on
  php_admin_flag safe_mode off
  php_admin_value open_basedir /var/www/vhosts/:/tmp/
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_php5.c>
php_admin_flag engine on
php_admin_flag safe_mode off
php_admin_value open_basedir /var/www/vhosts/:/tmp/
</IfModule>

</Directory>
```

Then, I simply needed to restart apache and it started to work.